# Ajax call unsuccessful in Asp.net

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, web-config, routeconfig

After debugging my application, I found that ajax call is unsuccessful.
I have tried multiple solutions found on web but still I am unable to resolve this issue.
One solution which I found is to set

```
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;
```

line in RouteConfig.cs but my RouteConfig.cs file does not contain this.
This is the code in RouteConfig.cs file.

[image: Routeconfig.cs]

I also tried this but still it made no difference

```
url: '<%= ResolveUrl("UploadProduct.aspx/SaveData") %>',
```

Code of Ajax call.

[image: Ajax function]

This is the Web method

[image]

Comment: what is the result ? http code ? 404 ? 500 ? Did you tried to call the method with Postman ?

Comment: To debug an Ajax call, it is recommended to use the `Network` tab in Google Chrome. It shows how the Ajax call is formed with all the parameters, and the response from the server.

Comment: Please don't post code as images. Copy your actual code into the question and format it as code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({

       url: "/Controller/ActionMethod/",
      method: "POST",
      data: {empdata: data}
     });
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.